# Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.DataExchange' while installing Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 Package

Tags: sitecore-commerce, packages, habitathome

I am trying to setup my Habitat Home Commerce solution (Sitecore Experience Commerce  9.0.2) and as a step for it I am trying to install the package `Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1` but received the below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.DataExchange,
>   Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

Reference:

- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Content/tree/upgrade/9.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error appear because you didn't install DataExchangeFramework module.

On the installation wizzard you will see next message:

### Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108

### Date: 08-Jan-2018

Before you install this package you must ensure the following 
packages are installed. If these packages are not installed, 
the installation will fail.

### - Sitecore Data Exchange Framework

Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 runs on:

### -  Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0.1 (and higher)

Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 
has been tested on:

### -  Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0.1

Sitecore® is a registered trademark. All other brand and
product names are the property of their respective holders.
The contents of this document are the property of Sitecore.
Copyright © 2001-2017 Sitecore. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install packages in correct order:

1. [Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/C50B044E45FE4C4DA9E675CBEED3AA09.ashx)
2. [Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/D57A1FBB98ED4125B78D740E5B5F1772.ashx)
3. [SQL Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/F243222B9A95497BAB6B591D39560E95.ashx)
4. [xConnect Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/C61F1265BB494CAFA4229FC9FC704AB0.ashx)
5. [Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/819FB4C75CC74A8C984C343BEF7B53F1.ashx)
6. [Sitecore Connect for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales 2.0.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/ADBAF4CC6736499EBA0EBA6A9767D825.ashx)

See Readme in https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Content/tree/upgrade/9.0.2 for further details.

Also take a look on very good guides made by Viet Hoang:

1. https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/08/01/sitecore-xp-9-0-2-and-sxa-1-7-1-demo-habitat-home-step-by-step-setup-guide/
2. https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/08/07/sitecore-xc-9-0-2-demo-habitat-home-commerce-step-by-step-setup-guide/